# How to specify a value of a child property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Environment is react functional component. Using a `useState` hook, I successfully retrieve JSON object from API call and can log it. However, I receive undefined attempting to log child property.

```
"data": {
  "id": 4876,
  "Number": "043-008",
  "Description": "On/Off Pull Chain Electrolier; Polished Brass",
  "Prod Cat": "Lamp Parts",
  "Mfg": "ADL",
  "Mfg Number": "D4110",
  "Warehouse": "2",
  "Warehouse Row": null,
  "Warehouse Shelf": null,
  "Color": "Polished Brass",
  "Stock Class": "W    ",
  "Unit of Measure": "      ",
  "Last Cost": 3.74
 }
}
```

console.log (data) is OK as displayed above, but data.id  is undefined.

Comment: Can you at least include the code producing the error, an executable code sandbox that reproduces your issue would be even better.

Comment: If console.log(data) logs what we see, you need to use console.log(data.data.id) since data is the variable name and there’s still a property called data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two scenarios how this might happen: First, you have an object with an attribute `data` in it. The value of `data` is then an object with `id` as an attribute. So, you need to access it that way: `data.data.id`. This might be confusing, but the first `data` is actually just the name of your variable and you can assign any name to it. The second one is depending on your JSON object.

A second problem might be that you are getting the object as a String representation of an object back from your API instead of an actual object. Try to parse it as JSON like this:

```
const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(parsedData.data.id);
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot. That data was coming from MSSQL. That statement was  res.json({ data: result.recordset[0] }); It should have been res.json(result.recordset[0]);